# Delete lines in a dataframe based on lookup in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I work with two dataframes. I want to remove lines in a first dataframe based on a match in another one.

In df1 I have two columns (called Type1 & Type2) + a flag.
I want to delete lines where flag = True & where Type1 & Type2 match a combination in another df2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 2)),columns = ["Type1","Type2"])
df1["Flag"] = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100))>6
df1.head()

  Type1  Type2   Flag
0      8      5  False
1      1      6  False
2      9      2  False
3      0      9   True
4      2      9  False

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 2)),columns = ["Type1","Type2"])
df2.head()

  Type1  Type2
0      0      9
1      7      8
2      5      1
3      3      3
4      3      2
```

For example here the line in df1 where index=3 should be deleted as Flag=True and (0,9) exists in df2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) for one df and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - need only values in `df1` (`left_only`) and `False` in `Flag`, so rows with `both` with `True` are deleted.

```
#on parameter omitted if only matched column are same in both df 
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', indicator=True)
#if multiple matched columns
#df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', indicator=True, on = ['Type1','Type2'])
print (df3)
   Type1  Type2   Flag     _merge
0      8      5  False  left_only
1      1      6  False  left_only
2      9      2  False  left_only
3      0      9   True       both
4      2      9  False  left_only

df3 = df3.loc[(df3['_merge'] == 'left_only') & (~df3['Flag']), ['Type1','Type2']]
print (df3)
   Type1  Type2
0      8      5
1      1      6
2      9      2
4      2      9
```

---

Also is possible create mask and then filter `df1` only (if many columns):

```
m = (df3['_merge'] == 'left_only') & (~df3['Flag'])
df1 = df1[m]
print (df1)
   Type1  Type2   Flag
0      8      5  False
1      1      6  False
2      9      2  False
4      2      9  False
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. I have difficulties to get out of my SQL logic.